# Ubuntu display setting not showing 4k resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, display-resolution

I have just received my new two 4k monitors for my dell desktop that mounts an NVIDIA Quadro K2200.

EDIT: the correct model is Dell S2722QC 27-inch

The problem is that in the display settings, the maximum resolution I am allowed to pick is 1920x1080.

At this moment, I have 3 monitors connected and the output of my xrandr is

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5040 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1200x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+3120+407 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    25.00    23.98    60.00    50.04  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1200+407 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    25.00    23.98    60.00    50.04  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  3840x2160_60.00 (0x262) 712.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4160 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock 134.18KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2237           clock  59.98Hz
```

I tried to force higher resolution using

```
cvt 3840 2160 60
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-0 "3840x2160_60.00"
```

but I get the following error

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  44
```

Also, this is what I get for edid

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
3 potential busses found: 1 2 3
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
128-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 1
If this isn't the EDID you were looking for, consider the other potential busses.
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DELL 2408WFP"
    ModelName "DELL 2408WFP"
    VendorName "DEL"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 18 of 2009
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 520 320
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-83
    VertRefresh 56-76
    # Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x1200, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 154.00 1920 1968 2000 2080 1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync 
EndSection
```

Can you help me fix this out?

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Dell 2408WFP is not a 4K display, it has 1920x1200 pixels.

Comment: Yes, the model is not identified correctly, I might have added that they are Dell S2722QC 27-inch

Comment: Are you using a DVI port and cable? DVI port can output max 2560 x 1600. Quadro K2200 has two DisplayPorts and if you use DP 1.2 cables, they should do.

Comment: I am using HDMI (screen) to DisplayPort (pc). Your comment suggested me to go look at the description of the cables, and indeed they provide up to 1920x1080 resolution! I am going to buy new ones that should match the 4k res. Do you have any to suggest?

Comment: Glad you solved this mystery. As per my experience, 2x Display Port Cable ver. 1.2 or better would have no problems. I prefer long cables, so that I can put a machine as far as 3 or 5 meters(15ft), I can take a nap on the front of displays.

Comment: The cables have arrived, and I can confirm that now everything works well, thank you again @SadaharuWakisaka !